# Determine number of pixels "length" of certain color/curve in simple image using Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, curve, hough-transform

I have a number of map images.  The background is *very* regular,  but I can have any number of "curved" paths.  See example (ignore the dot in the middle left):

[image: Simple Grid with uniform color paths]

Each path in the image is made up of at most three colors (denoting what sort of transport was taken) but these three colors don't change across paths (i.e. all paths use the same three colors).  These colors don't interfere at all with the background image.  Paths can start roughly from same position, and can cross.

I've tried Hough transforms to isolate the curves and it kind works, but given that there isn't much/any interference between the curves and the background, that seems overkill.

*Is there a way to just isolate the **colors** of the path and then just grab the pixel locations of those colors to recreate the paths in a grid?* (It might require an uncompressed image type, but I think I can do that).

I want to reverse engineer the "distance" these paths traverse, and just generally convert them from unstructured image data to structured (relative) "geo" data I can process. Once I do this I can explore path similarity, estimate total distance traveled, etc.  It's just a matter of scaling the number of pixels to the size/scale of the grid points, etc.

Comment: Thank *god* someone stepped in and converted my brackets to parenthesis.  Otherwise the [presumptive] meaning of my post would have been (completely) lost.

Comment: Are the colors always the same? If so you could convert the image to HSV color space and extract the specific colors.

Comment: Thanks @kavko, that's very helpful!  Yes, the colors from the path are all the same, or at least all from the same small subset.  The only question is whether those colors also appear in the background.  I don't think they do, but I'll do some exploration to see if this works.